# Переопределения представления для функционала бандла

Tags: поиск, symfony2, sylius

Успешно подключил `Sylius Search` в свой проект

https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusSearchBundle/blob/master/Controller/SearchController.php#L66
исходя из этой строчки задать свое представление из конфигов не получится

при попытке унаследоваться от данного контролера ошибка

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct() must be an instance of Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\Configuration, none given
```

В контроллере наличие конструктора не вижу. Как подключить указанный бандл с моим представлением?
как правильно работать с бандлами в принципе? Мне казалось что единственно верный путь указания `template` в конфигах, либо наследование

Comment: возможно нужно править services

Comment: Я бы не стал пользоваться наследованием, т.к. неизвестно, чего навертел создатель бандла. Проще всего переопределить сам шаблон в `app/Resources/SyliusSearchBundle/views/Search/index.html.twig` или по аналогичному пути.

Comment: я не совсем понял. Вы мне предлагаете править vendors?)
или речь о том что есть способ переопределения бандлов вне вендоров

Comment: у вас папка `app` лежит в `vendors`?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates

Comment: о полезная сылочка. сейчас пополню свой багаж знаниний

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по совету [Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki) ознакомился с

> http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates

в моем случае я успешно переопределил вывод поиска так:

```
app/Resources/SyliusSearchBundle/views/index.html.twig
```

так как 
https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusSearchBundle/blob/master/Controller/SearchController.php#L66

```
 ->setTemplate('SyliusSearchBundle::index.html.twig')
```

`app/Resources/SyliusSearchBundle/views/Search/index.html.twig` был бы актуальным если бы путь в контроллере бандла был `SyliusSearchBundle:Search:index.html.twig`